# How to get name of the test program along with dots while running ruby test

Tags: ruby, testunit

When I run my tests using rake I see dots as the tests are progressing. What I want is the name of the test program before the dots. I am getting some warnings but am not sure which test is throwing the warning. Getting the test name will help me immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a look at **[github.com/TwP/turn](http://github.com/TwP/turn)** -- it produces colorized output, outputs PASS/FAIL per test method *and*, most importantly, it shows you the relevant failure/error right after it has occured, not "after all the dots".

The [Readme](http://github.com/TwP/turn/blob/master/README.txt) at Github has all the relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
ruby test/test_name.rb --verbose
```

and to see other options for test/unit, you can run

```
ruby test/test_name.rb --help
```

Comment: I meant I am running a rake task and would like to see the name of test class before the dots.

Answer (score 0):

The test-unit gem adds better failing messages that will identify which test file had the failure. Just include it in your `Gemfile`

```
group :development do
  gem 'test-unit'
end
```

FYI, to get colorized output you can run the default rake task with `TESTOPTS`

```
bundle exec rake test TESTOPTS='--use-color'
```

Or you can have even more control by creating a custom rake task that uses `Rake::TestTask`

https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/testtask.rb

```
# lib/tasks/my_custom_test_runner.rake
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new("test:my_custom_test_runner") do |t|
   t.libs << "test"
   t.test_files = FileList['test/test*.rb']
   t.verbose = true
   t.opts = "--use-color"
end
```

Setting `t.verbose = true` will include in the output, the command used to run your tests based on the rake task you defined.